# Adding Map Annotation

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, ios4, mapkit

I have been trying to get multiple map pins to show on the map but it is not working. Can anyone help me out? I am using the code below:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad

  {
// Set some coordinates for our position (Buckingham Palace!)
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = (double) 51.501468;
location.longitude = (double) -0.141596;

// Add the annotation to our map view
MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Buckingham Palace" andCoordinate:location];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];


 }


 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], 1500, 1500);
[mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
[mv selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: In viewDidLoad, check if mapView is nil.  Does didAddAnnotationViews get called (put NSLog in it to check)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the mapview delegate?

```
self.mapView.delegate = self;
```